# Any way to increase figure size past screen size in MATLAB GUIDE?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, screen-size

I am working with a GUI in MATLAB created using GUIDE. There are quite a lot of components in it so it is not currently feasible to recreate it outside of GUIDE. I have been trying to implement Tabs into the GUI to display different Panels, each with their own set of components. I am doing this by adjusting the Visibility of each Panel to ON/OFF depending on which "tab" Button you click.

Now, when in the GUIDE editor, I would like to increase the figure size over the screen-size limit to allow me to easily work with each "Tab" Panel. When running the GUI, you would only ever see a single Panel, while all the other tabs will have their Visibility set to OFF.

Is there any way to have a larger figure size within the GUIDE editor itself?

Comment: Maybe you can configure your operating system to have a larger virtual screen size than the physical screen size?